# How to validate select box with Formik and Yup

Tags: next.js, formik, yup

I'm trying to validate a select box (dropdown) with Formik and Yup, but don't get it to work. It's working fine for text fields. For simplicity I cleaned up some code and use static option values:

```
  const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    category: yup
      .string()
      .required('category is required')
  });

  const defaultFormState = {
    category: ''
  }

return (

    <Formik
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      initialValues={defaultFormState}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
    >
      {(formik) => (
        <>
          <Row className={`${classes.overview} justify-content-center rounded`}>
            <Col>
              <h3>Test</h3>

              <Form>
                <div className={classes.formSection}>
                  <h3>Test form</h3>

                  
                  <label htmlFor="category" className="form-label">Categorie*</label>
                  <Field
                    as={FormSelectField}
                    options={categories}
                    name="category"
                  />
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name="category"
                    component={InputError}
                  />
                </div>
                
                <button disabled={formIsSubmitting} type="submit" className={`${classes.btnOrange} btn`}>Save</button>
              </Form>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
}
```

FormSelectField component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

function FormSelectField({ options, name }) {

  return <>
    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
      <select className="form-control" name={name} id={name}>
        <option value="test">test</option>
      </select>
    </Form.Group>
  </>;
}

export default FormSelectField;
```

Also added custom validation to log the value, but it gave "undefined", so seems it does not read the value.
Hope you guys can help me.